# Footer being cut while zoomin and zoomout

Tags: html, css

I have an issue in the design of my web page. If I set the wrapper's width to `1280px`, then the footer is being cut if I zoom in. But if I don't set the wrapper's width then footer is being cut while I'm zoomed out.

Any ideas on how I can handle this?

Comment: Please make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) of your code as an example. We can't help you without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a style `display: table; width:100%;` to your footer block. I hope it will help you